# automatic sorting and moving of files

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload, sorting, document-management, automation

was wondering if anyone could help me out with this idea I want to execute in SharePoint. so I have created a document directory for data migration, and I want to automate the whole system of uploading docs into these folders. so user A will upload into a temporary folder and then this file is automatically moved to its corresponding folder by a set of rules created.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using workflow. In the workflow, you could use copy list item then delete item actions. Start option set as "Start workflow automatically when an item is created.